¿Es necesario tener una base de datos para usar spring batch?
Quiero usar Spring Batch y me da un error de que falta el datasource, las soluciones son tener una base de datos normal o configurar una embebida:
<dependency>
<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
<artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<version>1.4.200</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Y poner esto en el properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Mi pregunta es si es obligatorio tener la base de datos, si es posible funcionar sin ella y cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo
Actualización
En el properties no tengo nada.
Intente hacer una app simple de toda, el proyecto es sacado del  spring initializr y haciendo éstas mínimas configuraciones.
La clase persona es un simple pojo con nombre, apellido y edad, construido con lombok
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class conf {
@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;
@Bean
public Job job (Step step1){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("xml")
            .repository(jobRepository)
            .start(step1)
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Step step1(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .transactionManager(transactionManager)
            .<Persona,Persona>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean

public ListItemReader<Persona> reader() {
    return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Persona("Juan", "Perez", 25),
            new Persona("Maria", "Lopez", 30)
    ));
}
@Bean
public ItemWriter<Persona> writer(){
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Persona>()
            .name("write")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("out.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter("|")
            .names(new String[] {"Nombre","Apellido","Edad"})
            .build();

}

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>batch</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-13 13:13:55.610 ERROR 17328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0


No es necesario. Algo tienes que tener definido que espera usar un datasource, quizá si añadieras el stacktrace del error te podríamos ayudar

añadí, el error y la configuración

He estado investigando y me he dado cuenta de que mi comentario está desactualizado: Por defecto Spring Batch ahora usa una base de datos para mantener un registro de las ejecuciones y resultados. Sus creadores consideran esta funcionalidad básica y dan por hecho que se declarará un datasource. Así que tienes dos opciones:

Añadir una base de datos, ya sea embebida como h2 o hsqldb, o externa como MySQL o PostgreSQL

Implementar la interfaz JobRepository para que no haga nada o use otro soporte (un fichero?) para guardar los datos de las ejecuciones.



como se diferenciarían las bds, en casos donde se use la h2 para batch, y por ejemplo dos mysql, siendo un step el que migra los datos de una a otra. En un archivo de configuración se podría tener la dos datasource con los mysql. Pero como indique que para spring batch utilize el h2. Como puedo indicar para que las diferencie, no se si me explico

Eso más bien es otra pregunta: ¿Como configurar distintos datasources en Spring?
